# Apply transform stream to write stream without controlling read stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have a function that expects a write stream to which I am providing the following stream:

```
const logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./log.txt')

fn(logStream)
```

`fn` is provided by a third-party module, so I do not control its implementation. Internally, I know that `fn` eventually does this:

```
// super simplified
fn (logStream) {
  // ...

  stream.pipe(logStream, { end: true })

  // ...
}
```

My issue is that I know that the read stream `stream` contains ANSI escape codes which I don't want to be outputted to my `log.txt`. After a quick google search, I found [`chalk/strip-ansi-stream`](https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi-stream), which is a transform stream designed to do just that.

So, being the Node streams newbie that I am, I decided to try to modify my code to this:

```
const stripAnsiStream = require('strip-ansi-stream')

const logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./log.txt')

fn(stripAnsiStream().pipe(logStream))
```

... which does not work: my log file still contains content **with the ANSI escape codes**. I think this is because instead of creating a chain like

```
a.pipe(b).pipe(c)
```

I've actually done

```
a.pipe(b.pipe(c))
```

---

How can I apply this transform stream to my write stream without controlling the beginning of the pipe chain where the read stream is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of chaining, stream.pipe() returns the input argument. The return value of `b.pipe(c)` is `c`.

When you call `fn(b.pipe(c))`, you're actually bypassing transform stream `b` and inputting the write stream `c` directly.

#### Case #1: a.pipe(b.pipe(c))

```
b.pipe(c)
a.pipe(c)
```

#### Case #2: a.pipe(b).pipe(c)

```
a.pipe(b)
b.pipe(c)
```

The transform stream can be piped into the log stream, and then passed into the module separately. You're effectively using case #2, but starting the pipes in reverse order.

```
const stripAnsiStream = require('strip-ansi-stream')
const fn = require('my-third-party-module')

const transformStream = stripAnsiStream()
const logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./log.txt')

transformStream.pipe(logStream)
fn(transformStream)
```